# Google Analytics - track custom dimensions to stop them being moved by other dev

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have implemented number of custom dimensions for Google Analytics tracking throughout my code base.

The challenge I have is that because the code base is being modified by other devs, my custom dimensions are moved or sometime removed. This causes inaccurate GA reports which i only find weeks later.

I am considering writing a script to pull dimension data daily from GA to monitoring the behavior of my dimensions, but not sure of this is the best approach.

Has any body had any experience with tracking/monitoring GA dimensions for anomalies to prevent them from dropping off?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest (best?) way to handle anomalies is with Google Analytics itself:**

• Create a segment of users/sessions including dimension matching any expected value

• Create a custom report with this segment to check data anytime

• Create an alert (admin > view > custom alerts) on decreasing traffic for this segment

• Send an email to yourself when this alert triggers

• Include the lead developer in the recipients :)

• Write a nice and detailed message

• Provide a link to the report in the message

Comment: Definitely a much easier solution. Thanks Neil.